# How to check for directory existence before creating it on remote server?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, command-line-interface, winscp

I'm transferring files from one server to another using `File Transfer Protocol` using the tool **WinSCP**, each type of file will have a separate directory to store, so before transferring I will have to create that directory. But when transferring the same type of file for the second time it gets failed because directory with the same name already exists.

Both the servers are using **Windows OS** so I am creating a batch file to transfer the files, the batch code below:-

```
@echo off

set user=%1
set type=%2
set input=D:\path\to\files\%user%\%type%\*.*


"WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="D:\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open ftp://users:passwords@127.0.0.1/" ^
    "mkdir %user%" ^
    "cd %user%" ^
    "mkdir %type%" ^
    "cd %type%" ^
    "put %input%" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%

if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

And here is the `WinSCP.log`:-

```
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.938 Using FTP protocol.
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.938 Doing startup conversation with host. 
> 2019-01-29 14:40:28.938 PWD
< 2019-01-29 14:40:28.938 257 "/" is the current directory.
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.938 Getting current directory name.
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.938 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2019-01-29 14:40:28.939 Script: Active session: [1] users@127.0.0.1
> 2019-01-29 14:40:28.939 Script: mkdir compo-sucks-a-little
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.939 Creating directory "compo-sucks-a-little".
> 2019-01-29 14:40:28.939 CWD /
< 2019-01-29 14:40:28.939 250 "/" is the current directory.
> 2019-01-29 14:40:28.939 MKD compo-sucks-a-little
< 2019-01-29 14:40:28.940 550 File exists.
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.940 Asking user:
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.940 Error creating folder 'compo-sucks-a-little'. ("File exists.")
< 2019-01-29 14:40:28.940 Script: Error creating folder 'compo-sucks-a-little'.
< 2019-01-29 14:40:28.940 Script: File exists.
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.941 Script: Failed
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.941 Script: Exit code: 1
. 2019-01-29 14:40:28.941 Disconnected from server
```

I want to check if directory already exists or not before creating it.

Comment: you can do `stat %type%" ^` then `exit`, the errorlevel will determine if the directory exists, simply create or don't create the directory based on that.

Comment: What happened when you tried to use [OPTION BATCH CONTINUE](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option)?

Comment: You should be able to `"mkdir /%user%/%type%" ^` followed by `"cd /%user%/%type%" ^`, there should be no need to make each branch as separate commands. As for your issue, and as mentioned by both Gerhard and Squashman, the only idea I can suggest, `"option batch continue" ^`, `"mkdir /%user%/%type%" ^`, `"option batch abort" ^`, `"stat /%user%/%type%" ^`.

Comment: @Compo That's indeed the correct solution. Would you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Compo Can you please explain to me what is the usage of `option` command? how it is helping here? And would be great if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @ShashankMishra, this is not a tutorial or reference material request site, please perform your own searches in future, [option :: WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option).

Comment: @Compo I just wanted you to explain your answer but nevermind thank you :)

Comment: @ShashankMishra, did you check the link I included in my comment? _(BTW, it wasn't technically an answer!)_

Comment: Yes, I checked it but it's a bit confusing so I am performing my own search as you said, And that is why I asked you to post it as an answer.